# iTunes App on macOS - play song now

Tags: itunes, music

I recently switched from Spotify to Apple Music. I cannot find any Play button next to the song's name in the app (as compared to Spotify). I cannot find the option to play the song now in place of the currently playing song - which is weird and annoying. A workaround for this is that I right-click on the name of the song, set it to Play Next and then use the >> button to move to the next song. Is this the only possible way or am I missing something?

OS version: 10.14.6 and app is up-to-date.

Screenshot of iTunes library page:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a double tap on the song name.

Comment: Okay, that worked. Should have tried that.